# How to launch a Spring webapp from within Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, spring, web-applications, launch

I've got a poor beginner question about Spring/Eclipse usage.

I'm working on tutorials to learn Spring, coding "Hello World" or other little webapps running few controllers and JSP.

Each time I wanna run the app from within Eclipse, nothing happens. I just get a 404 error.
In order to make the web app works, I have to run my Tomcat outside Eclipse (ie launch Tomcat from Windows with the startup.bat command line) and deploy a War through the manager-gui window of Tomcat.
So it works, but it would be more comfortable directly from within Eclipse on the embedded servers because this way running tests are so loooooooooong...

In Eclipse, I tried :

- Run on Server -> 404
- Run a Maven conf with Clean-Install goals,
  obtained a War, but was unable to use it from within Eclipse (it's
  the same War I use in the Tomcat GUI) as I saw it [here](http://crunchify.com/simplest-spring-mvc-hello-world-example-tutorial-spring-model-view-controller-tips/)

So can someone tell me how to run a Spring webapp from with Eclipse to make my work easier ?

Thanx by advance.

Comment: I never had any problem running Spring webapp in the Tomcat embedded in Eclipse. You see the project correctly when you right click on the tomcat server and "Add and Remove" ?
Any error in the Tomcat log? You may miss dependencies or a config file.

Comment: You have issue only with spring project? what about a sample dynamic web project ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7025781/tomcat-not-starting-from-eclipse, this will solve your issue. PLease check.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable 'Use Tomcat Installation' option in tomcat server when controlling it inside eclipse.
Please check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7025781/tomcat-not-starting-from-eclipse)
[Tomcat not starting from eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7025781/tomcat-not-starting-from-eclipse), this will solve your issue.